# How to add a Vuejs component to a Laravel Spark application?

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js

I am working on a Laravel 5.2 project with Laravel Spark (which still in beta as at time of writing) and trying to add some Vuejs functionality using the default layouts and views.

My first attempt failed because I simply tried to create a new `div` within the home view and bind my Vue code to that `div`. Here is the `div`:

```
    <div id="my-stuff">
        <p>@{{ test }}</p>
    </div>
```

And here is the corresponding JS code:

```
new Vue( {
    el: '#my-stuff',
    data: {
        test: 'This is a test'
    }
});
```

What I expected to see were the words "This is a test" appear within that div on the home screen, but of course nothing appeared because, as mentioned, Vue gets bound to a `div` immediately after the body tag (well, I'm assuming that's why anyway).

I think the solution to my problem is to use Vue components, which themselves look fairly straightforward, but I have no idea where to put my code, how to integrate my code with the Gulp process, which Spark file I need to modify (if any?) to register my component and how to ensure that my component gets registered before the Vue instance gets created.

Any help would be much appreciated.

**Addendum 1**

To reproduce the exact same set-up as I'm using, one would need to install a fresh copy of Laravel 5.2, then use the spark installer to add the spark stuff, then add `app.js` containing the code below to the `public` folder, add the corresponding `div` anywhere in the `home` view and add a script tag to include `app.js` right below the script tag that imports the main javascript file produced by gulp.

Whilst it is impractical to reproduce that entire setup in a fiddle, I think the following fiddle illustrates the essence of the problem:

https://jsfiddle.net/5oLLte2e/

From memory you have the same limitation in AngularJS. It is completely reasonable to me why this wouldn't work and the solution in Vuejs is most likely to use components, but the challenge in this situation is knowing how to bundle the component and where to save it in order to integrate it with the gulp config, or if that is even necessary.

Comment: Vue should be binding directly to the div you are indicating by the value of `el`. Can you reproduce in a fiddle?

Comment: Where are you including your vue script? It has to go in the body, not in the head.

Comment: @DavidK.Hess I have created a fiddle that illustrates the essence of the problem and added a link to the fiddle in the question.

Comment: @gurghet I am including app.js in the body, a few lines from the end, just after the main app.js that is produced by gulp is included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Vuejs Components**

If you want to have more than one vue instance **the short answer is: yes**, you need components.

```
<div id="main-app">
<p>{{ mainMessage }}</p>
    <my-app>
        <p>Some composable content</p>
    </my-app>
</div>
```

And the scripts will have to be loaded components first:

```
Vue.component('my-app', {
  template: '<div>{{myMessage}}<br/><slot></slot></div>',
  data: function() {
    return {
      myMessage: 'This is my message'
    }
  }
});

new Vue( {
  el: '#main-app',
  data: {
    mainMessage: 'This is the main module'
  }
});
```

The output will be:

```
This is the main module
This is my message
Some composable content
```

Here is the fiddle: [Components with Vue](https://jsfiddle.net/x84ykhc1/)

Remember that you can always put the template in the page using a unique id or, more idiomatically using something like:

```
<script type="x/template" id="my-app">
  Your template here
  {{ your component variables }}
</script>
```

---

**Laravel Spark Integration**

The steps to adding a component within a Sparkified Laravel application are as follows:

(1) Add the placeholder HTML with the custom tag anywhere on the page, even if a surrounding div has already been Vue-ified. The HTML with the custom component might look like this:

```
<div id="example">
    <my-component></my-component>
</div>
```

(2) Implement the Vue component and save the JavaScript file in `resources/assets/js`. By way of example, we might save the following code as `my-component.js`:

```
var MyComponent = Vue.extend({
    data: function() {
        return { message: 'This is a test' }
    },

    template: '{{ message }}'
})

Vue.component('my-component', MyComponent)

new Vue({
    el: '#example'
})
```

(3) Add one `require` statement (the second line below) to the code in `resources/assets/js/app.js` so that the file looks like this:

```
require('laravel-spark/core/bootstrap');
require('./my-component.js'); // This is the key!

new Vue(require('laravel-spark'));
```

Note that it is super-important to include the leading `./` in front of the filename, otherwise Browserify will assume it is looking for a `npm` module instead of a raw file and will fail.

(4) Run `gulp` and once it has finished, refresh the page. Gulp will call Browserify, which processes `resources/assets/js/app.js`, which now includes our custom JavaScript to be processed and included in the final `public/js/app.js` file.

If you carry out these steps on a clean Laravel installation that has had the Spark installer treatment (I made my mods to `home.blade.php`), you should see the sample text appear on the page.

Comment: Thank you for your answer - it is definitely very helpful. However, a significant part of the question is about where to put the JavaScript code and this is where the Spark-related stuff comes in. I have made a little more progress myself. I have discovered that the Spark installer drops a file called app.js into the project's resources/assets/js folder and this appears to be the right place to bootstrap my components, as this file won't be overwritten by composer updates and is already configured to be picked up by Elixir/gulp. Now I need to work out the right way to utilize this facility.

Comment: BTW - If I can solve that last piece of the puzzle myself I will add that to your answer and accept it, as I really appreciate the effort you put into demonstrating the Vue side of things.